# Future does not complete reliably in Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, future

A piece of code using Play Framework 2.3

```
def signup = Action(parse.json) { implicit request =>
  val email = (request.body \ "email").asOpt[String]

  val holder =
    WS.url("https://foobar.com/foo")
      .withAuth("1234","5678",WSAuthScheme.BASIC)

  val data = Json.obj(
    "email" -> email,
  )

  holder.post(data)
  Ok("OK")
}
```

This code will perform the post() when run locally on my machine, but not reliably on remote machines. From my understanding the post() call should create and return a future, signup() returns Ok(), the future is run on the default ExecutionContext and at some point completes and is cleaned up. Apparently this is not the case.

I have since changed the function to be an Action.async and am now waiting on the Future:

```
val res = holder.post(data)
res.map( x => Ok(Json.obj("status" -> "OK"))) recover {
  case (e: Exception) =>
    InternalServerError(Json.obj("status" -> "Not OK."))
}
```

This works reliably. Hence, my questions:

- Why does the first version not work reliably?
- How can I in general "fork off" a long running procedure, without intention of waiting on it, purely for its side-effects, if not like I did in version 1?

Comment: What do you mean by **reliably**?

Comment: Locally it always worked, deployed in production it worked when first tested, a few days later no more WS requests came through, despite signup() returning successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's near impossible to say why the `Future` isn't completing "reliably", but I'd hazard a guess that there's something wrong with the web service you're trying to reach. SSL problems, timeouts not being reached,.. the possibilities are large without knowing what exception is being thrown (if any?).

If you don't want to wait on the WS call, you can use the `onComplete` callback:

```
val res = holder.post(data)

res.onComplete {
    case Success(response) =>
        // Create some side-effect to the response
    case Failure(e) =>
        // The `Future` failed.
}
```

Comment: I agree Exception logging would have helped. So what you're saying is that the way it was written should work. If so, that's good enough for me.

Comment: Yes, you should definitely log whatever exception may be happening from the failed `Future` to figure out why it's failing. It's also possible that the remote server is closing the connection improperly, causing you to wait for nothing. Again, hard to tell without more info.